# How to install Oracle jdk 15 on Debian 10 Buster

Tags: java, oracle, debian

**I'm trying to install Oracle's JDK 15 on vanilla Debian Buster 10 headless server.
I downloaded the Oracle's Linux x64 Debian Package, but the installation somehow fails without any apparent errors:**

```
sudo dpkg -i ./jdk-15.0.2_linux-x64_bin.deb


(Reading database ... 59385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./jdk-15.0.2_linux-x64_bin.deb ...
Unpacking jdk-15.0.2 (15.0.2-1) over (15.0.2-1) ...
Setting up jdk-15.0.2 (15.0.2-1) ...
```

it seems ok, but then:

```
java --version
```

gives me:

```
command not found
```

Comment: You need to set the PATH variable. In [this guide](https://www.javahelps.com/2019/04/install-latest-oracle-jdk-on-linux.html) step 6.

Comment: @Alex Thanks! That's really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way be adding `java` and `javac` to `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.2/bin/java 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15.0.2/bin/javac 100
```

Next you will be able to use `java` and `javac` commands.

If you have a multiples `java`, `javac` versions, use the following command to switch between them:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: Great! It does give me the **java** command, but no **javac**.

Comment: I guess one needs to change the **PATH** variable, but what I do not understand is why all of this is not automatically configured when installing  with `dpkg -i`

Comment: @Peter Answer edited to includ `javac`. I know this should work by setting up `$PATH` , but I need to answer this question differently.